# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 5: invalid start byte

Tags: python, pandas

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('db.csv')
data.head()
data.drop(['Company Rate', 'Metascore', 'Minutes Release Budget', 'Opening Weekend USA', 'Gross USA'], axis=0)

data.to_csv('db2.csv', encoding='utf-8')
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/christine/Documents/Christine-CS/ALT 2/ALT2 Project/clean db2.py", line 3, in <module>
    data = pd.read_csv('db.csv')
  File "/Users/christine/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 688, in read_csv
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/Users/christine/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 454, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(fp_or_buf, **kwds)
  File "/Users/christine/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 948, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "/Users/christine/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1180, in _make_engine
    self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
  File "/Users/christine/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 2010, in __init__
    self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 537, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 740, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._get_header

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 5: invalid start byte
```

Comment: It looks like db.csv isn't utf-8 encoded. Do you know what wrote the file and what encoding it used?

Comment: Im pretty sure its utf-8 because i exported it to a csv in that format

Comment: Can you post the first bit of the file so we can experiment? `print(open('db.csv', 'rb').read(32))` would be plenty as the error is hit by the 5th character. You could try your own experiments, e.g., `open('db.csv', encoding="utf-16-le").read(32)` and see if you get the right text.

Comment: Original Title Company Rate Metascore Minutes Release Budget Opening Weekend USA Gross USA Gross Worldwide
1 Iron Man Marvel 7.9 79 126 2008 140000000 98618668 318604126 585366247
2 The Incredible Hulk Marvel 6.7 61 112 2008 150000000 55414050 134806913 263427551
3 Iron Man 2 Marvel 7 57 124 2010 200000000 128122480 312433331 623933331
4 Thor Marvel 7 57 115 2011 150000000 65723338 181030624 449326618

Comment: It didn't come out right as its a table on marvel and dc movies for an ALT Im working on

Answer (score 0):

Do you get the same error if you use:

```
data.to_csv('db2.csv', encoding='latin1')
```

Comment: latin1 can read any data file without error, but if it wasn't encoded in latin1 it will contain incorrect code points.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/christine/Documents/Christine-CS/ALT 2/ALT2 Project/clean db2.py", line 7
    data.to_csv('db2.csv' encoding='latin1')
                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax